# Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, String or binary data would be truncate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

I have procedure which put records to table, specifically from field data type `money` to field data type `numeric(11,0)`  by

```
insert into tab1(decimal_field_1) 
    select convert(numeric(11, 0), money_field_1) 
    from tab2
```

After execution I get information with warning:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14
> String or binary data would be truncated

I consciously convert that column from `money` to `decimal(11,0)` and I don't want to use `set ansi_warnings OFF`.

So what wrong I do? How correctly convert that data?

Answer (score 0):

That error is typically involved in truncating strings (e.g., varchar, nvarchar) rather than numbers (e.g., the string is too long to fit).

If I have a too-large money value converting to numeric(11,0), it gives me the error `Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 5 Arithmetic overflow error converting money to data type numeric.`

As such, the error is unlikely to be triggered by the CONVERT, but instead in the INSERT. You could test this by just doing a `select convert(numeric(11, 0), money_field_1) from tab2` which should work OK - showing the CONVERT is fine.

Are you only inserting into 1 column decimal_field_1?

- If so, are you sure that decimal_field_1 is also numeric(11,0) rather than a varchar or nvarchar?
- If you are inserting other columns, check the other fields. It's likely the error is coming from there.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I checked other columns and problem is in that one. I tested also this CONVERT in select query and it is working well - without warning. So it must be triggered in the INSERT, I think.

Comment: Yeah - your table's field decimal_field_1 is likely to not be correct e.g. not `numeric(11,0)`

Comment: I've made a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d4f9aa4eabbe4527c68fb19f2099a7cd) showing the error when you have too-large numbers. It is different from too-large strings. If your CONVERT works as a SELECT, but fails on INSERT, then there's something wrong with the target field imo.

Answer (score 0):

The money data type has been deprecated for a while.  Have a look at this [article](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/avoid-use-money-smallmoney-datatypes) about avoiding it.

> "MONEY is accurate between -922,337,203,685,477.5808 (-922,337
> trillion) and 922,337,203,685,477.5807 (922,337 trillion)"

Try using DECIMAL(19, 4)

```
insert into tab1(decimal_field_1) 
    select convert(numeric(19, 4), money_field_1) 
    from tab2;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need convert exactly to numeric(11,0) or to DECIMAL(11,0) also.

Comment: What if the number is too large to fit?